# Unable to use template in TypeSafe Activator

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I've just downloaded TypeSafe Activator 3.5 (the latest at this moment)

I've run the .bat (because I'm under windows 7) and everything seems to have installed perfectly.

The activator UI opened in Chrome and I selected the "Reactive Stock" template to activate it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have this error:

"Could not load build configuration" with more detail in the background log (see image)

[image]

How can I get over this problem? Is there some prerequisite that I need to have for this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

It seems that the problem was simply my version of java. I was using 1.6_45 and theses examples needs java 1.8_X. Changing the JAVA_HOME for this new path, restarting my machine (maybe not needed) and trying again worked.

It's a shame that the error message is not clearer but I hope this question will help people in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Sbt and scala compiler require Java 8. Above message says that you have java 7 installed